# How to calculate endPoint using initial point, distance and azimuth?

Tags: c#, math, distance, latitude-longitude, azimuth

I need to find the endpoint using the start point, distance and azimuth. Here are the values of each one:

```
latitude: 37.624942,
longitude": -7.896333,
azimute: 233.0
distance : 20.0
```

Here is my function:

```cs
private List<double> findEndPoint(string latitudeStart, string longitudeStart, string azimute,double distancia) 
{
    List<double> endPoint = new List<double>();

    double latitudeStartDouble = Convert.ToDouble(latitudeStart, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    double longitudeStartDouble = Convert.ToDouble(longitudeStart, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    double azimuteDouble = Convert.ToDouble(azimute, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    double azimuteRadians = ConvertToRadians(azimuteDouble);

    
    double R = 6371.0; // Raio da Terra em km

    

    double latitudeEnd = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(latitudeStartDouble) * Math.Cos(distancia / R) +
        Math.Cos(latitudeStartDouble) * Math.Sin(distancia / R) * Math.Cos(azimuteRadians));

    endPoint.Add(latitudeEnd);

    double longitudeEnd = longitudeStartDouble + Math.Atan2(
        Math.Sin(azimuteRadians) * Math.Sin(distancia / R) * Math.Cos(latitudeStartDouble),
        Math.Cos(distancia / R) - Math.Sin(latitudeStartDouble) * Math.Sin(latitudeEnd));

    endPoint.Add(longitudeEnd);

    return endPoint;
}
```

It returns:

```
latitude: -0.0760588400705975
longitude:-7.8988473639987093
```

The latitude must be wrong, but I don't know why is it giving me that value.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `latitudeStartDouble`. You just calculate the delta. So `latitudeEnd = latitudeStartDouble + ...etc...`

Answer (score 0):

I need to be working with radians and then converting it back to degrees:

```
private List<double> findEndPoint(string latitudeStart, string longitudeStart, string azimute,double distancia) 
    {
        List<double> endPoint = new List<double>();

        double latitudeStartDouble = Convert.ToDouble(latitudeStart, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        latitudeStartDouble = ConvertToRadians(latitudeStartDouble);

        double longitudeStartDouble = Convert.ToDouble(longitudeStart, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        longitudeStartDouble = ConvertToRadians(longitudeStartDouble);

        double azimuteDouble = Convert.ToDouble(azimute, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        double azimuteRadians = ConvertToRadians(azimuteDouble);


        double R = 6371; // Raio da Terra em km

        

        double latitudeEnd = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(latitudeStartDouble) * Math.Cos(distancia / R) +
            Math.Cos(latitudeStartDouble) * Math.Sin(distancia / R) * Math.Cos(azimuteRadians));

        latitudeEnd = ConvertToDegrees(latitudeEnd);
        endPoint.Add(latitudeEnd);

        double longitudeEnd = longitudeStartDouble + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(azimuteRadians) * Math.Sin(distancia / R) * Math.Cos(latitudeStartDouble),
            Math.Cos(distancia / R) - Math.Sin(latitudeStartDouble) * Math.Sin(latitudeEnd));

        longitudeEnd = ConvertToDegrees(longitudeEnd);
        endPoint.Add(longitudeEnd);

        return endPoint;
    }
```