# how to calculate geo cordinates of sector points given center and azimuth

Tags: geolocation, geometry, geo

I have geo coordinates of center point, radius and azimuth and sector angle are also known. Based on these parameters what I would like to calculate GEO coordinates of sector points. Please check the image for exact problem.

[image]

I checked following question but not exactly what I am looking for. i am completely knew to GEO spatial geometry.

[How to calculate endPoint using initial point, distance and azimuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476695/how-to-calculate-endpoint-using-initial-point-distance-and-azimuth)

Comment: What azimuth is known? Picture does not show it.

Comment: The direction of the sector is known in degrees.

Comment: What is direction of the sector? Please mark at the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should give you the required endpoints. I took reference from [Geo Distance with Azimuth](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/article.php/c5115/Geographic-Distance-and-Azimuth-Calculations.htm).
You just need to change the Azimuth for the sector points.

```
type GeoPoint struct {
    Longitude float64
    Latitude  float64
}

findEndPoint(lon float64, lat float64, azimuth float64, distance float64) GeoPoint {
    b := distance / 6371.0

    a := math.Acos(math.Cos(b)*math.Cos(convertToRadians(90-lat)) + math.Sin(convertToRadians(90-lat))*math.Sin(b)*math.Cos(convertToRadians(azimuth)))
    B := math.Asin(math.Sin(b) * math.Sin(convertToRadians(azimuth)) / math.Sin(a))

    lat2 := 90 - convertToDegrees(a)
    lon2 := convertToDegrees(B) + lon

    return GeoPoint{lon2, lat2}
}

point1 := findEndPoint(lon, lat, azimuth-(beamWidth/2), distance)
point2 := findEndPoint(lon, lat, azimuth+(beamWidth/2), distance)
```